# What is the better way to get swing components

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I am using Window Builder plugin for Eclipse to build a Java Swing Desktop application Front End.
The problem is that on Action Listener when I want to get the value of the components, I individually get the component by index.
See code snippet

```
public class SomeListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


        //button from which action is triggered 
        JButton startTestButton = (JButton) event.getSource();

        //components 
        Component[] components = startTestButton.getParent().getComponents();           

        //Get individual components
        JCheckBox endUserLabel = (JCheckBox) components[0];
    }   
}
```

The problem is , when ever new element is added to container, lets say a JTextBox, the index of all the elements is changed. Is there any better way to achieve this ?

Comment: You mean you want to add component on some action event?

Comment: @rachana No, I meant that if there are many components, then restructuring component's places or adding them to container will lead to class cast Exception i.e. `JCheckBox endUserLabel = (JCheckBox) components[4];` will through exception b/c the label might be on some other index.

Comment: Then just check if it is JCheckBox.class before executing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't depend on the index in `getComponents()`.   Instead setup your `ActionListener` with the correct references it needs or a reference to a controller object that can make the changes in the GUI that are needed.  Do this all before the `actionPerformed()` method gets called.

As a side note, if you are going to be continuing to work on this project, throw out the GUI builder and code by hand.  It will save you effort long term and will help you to learn Swing faster.

Comment: I am actually populating my class object by getting these component's value in `ActionListener`. Can you show by example what are you trying to say ? Did you mean that I use bean binding framework so that my model object is already populated when call is made to `ActionListener` ?

Comment: I am not talking about a bean binding framework.  I am talking about just a simple reference to your components to be able to access their values directly instead of relying on the parent components list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access specific widgets in a listener, you need to either track them or provide a way to resolve them.

Tracking solutions:

- create attributes (instance fields) for the widgets
- track the widgets in a map

Solution with resolving:

- Set the 'name' property on your widgets, and create a method with resolves them by name in the component tree.

Even better solution:

- Use Data Binding, so changes on widgets get reflected on the presentation model, and read/write values always over the model, not the widgets.

Example with tracking:

```
final JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setName("userinput");

JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Text: " + textField.getText());
    }
});
```

Comment: I will opt Even Better Solution :), do you recommend any easy bean binding solution, which populates data on DataModel ?

Comment: Have a look at JGoodies Binding: http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/